# Are there ways this question might be improved so that it gets a good answer?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, improvement

Is there a better way to ask this question, "[Validating need for documentation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/210664/validating-need-for-documentation?noredirect=1#comment415051_210664)" - since this seems like a question that has an answer, but then again, I might be wrong.

I've attempted to state the question clearly, give examples, provide context, and answer comments - but I get the feeling the question could be improved.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would probably move this part from the bottom to top, to highlight specific problem: _"I once was on a project where a non-tech manager had the team spending half of every hour documenting what they just did so that someone if zero understanding of the tech would be able to understand the tech. Personally, I thought this was a huge waste, but there was no way to validate this was or was not waste."_

Comment: +1 @gnat: Good point, updated the question, thank you for taking the time to give feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was the first paragraph that caught my attention.

I thought this was okay, could have been a little more specific about what documentation was being asked for, but it sounded good:

> I once was on a project where a non-tech manager had the team spending
>   half of every hour documenting what they just did so that someone with
>   zero understanding of the tech would be able to understand the tech

But it was this that caught my attention. It appeared that you had made up your mind what you wanted to hear as an answer. To me it would have been much better to hear why you felt the time-wasting documentation was distracting you from your work or let everyone come to their own conclusions.

> Personally, I thought this was a huge waste, but there was no way to
>   validate this was or was not waste.

Comment: Above is just my opinion.